# Getting "no such file or directory". Why?

Tags: command-line, files, executable

Why am I getting the following error?

```
# whoami
root

# ls -l seamonkey
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 127044 Dec 13 22:11 seamonkey

# ./seamonkey
bash: ./seamonkey: No such file or directory


# LC_ALL=C find -type f -iname "*seamonkey*" -printf "'%P'\n"
'seamonkey'
'seamonkey-bin'
'chrome/icons/default/seamonkey.png'



# readelf -l seamonkey
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x804c278
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00120 0x00120 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000154 0x08048154 0x08048154 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x1e610 0x1e610 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x01e610 0x08067610 0x08067610 0x003cc 0x0067c RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x01e6fc 0x080676fc 0x080676fc 0x00110 0x00110 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x000168 0x08048168 0x08048168 0x00044 0x00044 R   0x4
  TLS            0x01e610 0x08067610 0x08067610 0x00000 0x00004 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x019490 0x08061490 0x08061490 0x00d2c 0x00d2c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .ctors .dtors .jcr .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .tbss 
   07     .eh_frame_hdr 
   08     

$ ldd ./seamonkey
not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: The error is (probably) from the linker...Is the file binary? If so, what is the output of `readelf -l seamonkey`; if it's a script, add it's contents to your question...

Comment: # readelf -l seamonkey

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x804c278
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 52

Comment: Can you try this one please  and add  output either to your question or to paste.ubuntu.com (in fact, please just add things to your original post. The comments don't allow for proper formatting of text at all) `LC_ALL=C find -type f -iname "*seamonkey*" -printf "'%P'\n"` Just a hunch, maybe there's special characters in the filename.  Consider also trying `find -type f -iname "*seamonkey*" | hexdump -C`

Comment: I don't know how to "add output to question".# LC_ALL=C find -type f -iname "*seamonkey*" -printf "'%P'\n"
'seamonkey'
'seamonkey-bin'
'chrome/icons/default/seamonkey.png'

Comment: Add all the outputs the your question, not on comment...

Comment: @David look  below your post. There should be 3 buttons in your view: share, edit, and flag.  Click the edit one

Comment: Does the file `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` exist?

Comment: Run `ldd ./seamonkey`, that should list missing required libraries, if any

Comment: File ld-linux.so.2 does not appear to exist. I'm just following installation instructions as given on the seamonkey web site. It that doesn't work I'm done with seamonkey.

Comment: Your `readelf` output indicates a 32-bit executable, if you're using a 64-bit system, see linked duplicate post.

Comment: Bingo muru! I just downloaded 64-bit version of seamonkey and it works. Thanks!

Comment: How come it's so easy to install apps on Windows and so hard on Linux? Will it ever be fixed?